# how to format SelectSingleNode xPath with index #?

Tags: c#, xml

i want to SelectSingleNode with index # since i have few elements with the same path.

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPath).InnerText = xValue.ToString();
```

When xPath is the following string:

"/Parameter [@tag='tool_od']/Value/ValueSeries/**Value[Index=1]**/value"

or
"/Parameter [@tag='tool_od']/Value/ValueSeries/**Value[1]**/value"

or 
"/Parameter [@tag='tool_od']/Value/ValueSeries/**Value[@Index=1]**/value"

all of those options gives me an error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

this is the part of the xml:
i want to be able to access each of  childs with selectsinglenode.

```
<ValueSeries>
            <Value>
              <value>25</value>
            </Value>
            <Value>
              <value>999012.0</value>
            </Value>
            <Value>
              <value>999012.0</value>
            </Value>
</ValueSeries>
```

if i will remove the index part the path will work fine but it will only access the first element  and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure what exactly your problem is without being able to see your input xml.

Note that you don't need to use `xDoc.DocumentElement` as your xpath is referring to the root node anyway (/), so you can just do `xDoc.SelectSingleNode(...`.

If you are looking for the first "Value" element of "ValueSeries" your second xpath looks correct (does a value contain a value?),  but it depends on what your xml looks like.

The "Object reference" error is due to the fact that SelectSingleNode is returning null (as your xpath is not found), and you are trying to set the property InnerText.

Answer (score 0):

my error was due of using index "0", the first index is 1.

Comment: this wasn't clear from your question, where you are using [1] (and yes xpath is 1-based)